# Get current schema version from java using XmlBeans

Tags: java, xmlbeans

`XmlBeans` provides the possibility of validating an object against a underlying xsd by invoking `XmlObject#validate`.

This there any way to obtain a reference to the XSD file used for the validation? Concrete I am looking for a way to get the schema version.